# How do I scroll to a specific section with a link using full page.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I'm using the fabulous [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs) to make a single page website.

Here's the basic code:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section0">
        <h1>Page 0</h1>
        <p>Some text 0</p>      
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <p>Some text 1</p>      
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
        <p>Some text 2</p>      
    </div>
</div>
```

What I can't figure out is how to include a link in section 0 to section 2 (i.e. just a standard `<a href>` link). I've been messing around with anchors but can't get it to work.

Comment: Did what was listed here not work for you? https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#using-anchor-links

Comment: If I add `data-anchor="last-section"` to `#section2` and then add `<a href="#last-section">click me</a>` in #section1's content, the link does nothing...

Comment: @Alvaro 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23136819/4497502) is solves my issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You only need to use the `anchors` option and then use normal links:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['section1', 'section2', 'section3', 'section4']
});
```

The link should look normally, but prefixed bye `#`:

```
<a href="#section3">Link to section 3</a>
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/100/)

Your URLs will look like:

```
http://yoursite.com/#section1
http://yoursite.com/#section2
http://yoursite.com/#section3
http://yoursite.com/#section4
```

Now it is also possible to use the html attribute `data-anchor="section1"` in each section in order to define the anchor for it. For example:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" data-anchor="section1">Section 1</div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="section2">Section 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. I hadn't realised that the anchors property of the fullpage initialisation referenced the sections in the order that they are defined. Thanks a lot Alvaro. Great script btw.

Comment: That was helpful, however to use anchor links pointing to a particular section, one must use the anchor option while initializing fullpage.js.

Comment: @Ashesh as its detailed in the answer :)

Comment: For others: Be careful! data-anchor tags can not have the same value as any ID element on the site (or NAME element for IE).